# Unable to remove dynamically created UIButton inside for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app where the contacts phone numbers are listed depending on the number of phone numbers stored for the contact. I need a button corresponding to every phone number. I have written a for loop with an if condition

Now when user taps on a contact with 3 numbers the button is shown perfectly then he presses back button and goes to a contact with 1 number and still all the three buttons are showed.
I have tried [btn autorelease]; [btn setEnabled:NO];  [btn removeFromSuperView];
but still the problem isn't resolved. Below is the snipped of code :

```
    for (int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(lMap);i++)   {
        if (i==0)   {
     //       UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            btn.frame = CGRectMake(230,110,88,35); //The position and size of the button (x,y,width,height)
            [btn setTitle:@"SMS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showAbout)
          forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];
            [btn autorelease];

        }
        else if (i==1)  {
       //     UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(230,150,88,35); //The position and size of the button (x,y,width,height)
            [btn setTitle:@"SMS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showAbout)
          forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];
                            [btn autorelease];
        }
        else if (i==2)  {
      //      UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(230,190,88,35); //The position and size of the button (x,y,width,height)
            [btn setTitle:@"SMS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showAbout)
          forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:btn];
             [btn autorelease];
        }
```

Comment: include the code where your remove the button(s)

Comment: this is the complete code.. i am new to iOS so i am not sure how to fix it. [btn autorelease]; throws an message sent to deallocated instance error.ABMultiValueGetCount(lMap) is the total number of contacts and i am trying to display a button named SMS in front of each contact but when i click the back button and again click another contact it displays 3 button (say previous contact had 3 phone numbers)

Comment: are you storing _all_ buttons in an array maybe you have created; or you are storing _only the last button_ in a property and you are just waiting some kinda miracle for the rest `x-1` button would be removed from itself? because that I guess the latest happens here...

Comment: I declared the button just before the for loop 'UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];'     Nop, i am not storing it in a array. Is that going to solve my issue ?

Comment: you never remove any buttons

Comment: You don't need to store the button(s) in an array. The viewController's view (self.view) does that for you by copying it into it's subviews property (when you add it as a subview). Simply give the button a tag, and when you need to remove it, go through the self.view.subviews array and remove the button with the correct tag from its superview.

Comment: What method is this code in? If it is in viewDidAppear then it will be executed again when you return to that view and will cause the buttons to be added again.

Comment: @KoreyHinton Hi.. it is inside loadData method.. which is being called in setContact method          `- (void)setContact:(ABRecordRef)acontact {
    if(contact != nil && ABRecordGetRecordID(contact) == kABRecordInvalidID) {
        CFRelease(contact);
    }
    contact = acontact;
    [self loadData];
    [headerController setContact:contact];
}`

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [headerController view]; // Force view load
    [footerController view]; // Force view load

    
}`

Comment: @AnkitKhanna It sounds like they getting re-added as subviews after you save the contact. If you need to re-generate the buttons then make sure you can lookup the old ones and remove them. Use view.tag with viewWithTag method or save the views as properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
// Declare a constant
int buttonTagConstant = 200;

// Before creating the buttons, delete the old ones first.
for (UIView* subV in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([subV isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && subV.tag == buttonTagConstant) 
    {
        [subV removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

int y_of_the_button = 110;

// Also I refactored your code as below
for (int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(lMap);i++)
{
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(230, y_of_the_button, 88, 35); //The position and size of the button (x,y,width,height)
    [btn setTitle:@"SMS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showAbout) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn.tag = buttonTagConstant;
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    y_of_the_button += 40;
}
```

Comment: Hi... @ondermerol..  thanks a ton for helping me out... but this still isn't solving my problem...   Autorelease is somewhat helpful but after some repeat back click and then tap on the phone number it shows an error.. "Message sent to deallocated address"

Comment: The code you have provided above only print the button once. But still i really appreciate the help!    I should describe my issue once  again. I am working on an app that has a contact section, i have to add a sms button in front of every contact that is listed out... say if Mr. jack has one contact and Mr. Robert has 3 contact... with the auto release code what is happening is when I tap on Mr. Jack it correctly displays one "SMS" button.. i press back button Code: `[[PhoneMainView instance] popCurrentView];`   ..cntd.

Comment: and it takes me back to list of the contact and then i press Mr. Robert contact it takes me to the phone numbers and list out correctly buttons as well. but now if i press the back button it throws an error saying "Message sent to deallocated address"   I am new to iOS and i am not able to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Oh sorry! i didn't change the value of 110 with y_of_the_button .. this solves my problem... Thanks a kilo, quintal and tons... :D

Comment: Can you try it again? I edited the code (missed setting new buton's y value of the frame to be equal to the parameter y_of_the_button not 110.)

Comment: Hi @ondermerol... sorry to bother you again... I am facing one more issue related to same problem... in the same view there is one edit button when i press it these buttons are shown in that view as well which shouldn't happen. i tried to implement this code in the edit button click method but it is not going inside the if condition. And now again i need expert advice :)

Comment: Ok, problem is solved by using a Post Notification :)